# How to transform an XML List to an Object with Mule 3.2 JAXB Transformers?

Tags: java, list, jaxb, transform, mule

If I read this XML from a JMS queue and use **mulexml:jaxb-xml-to-object-transformer** to transform it into a carType Java how do I need to set up my Java Class to get this information into a List I can use later.

```
<carTypes>
 <car>
 <name>Toyota</name>
 <color>red</color>
 </car>
 <car>
 <name>Ford</name>
 <color>Blue</color>
 </car>
</carTypes>
```

I was trying something like this but its not working

```
 package org.mule.jaxb.model;

 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
 import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

 @XmlRootElement(name = "carTypes")
 public class Cars{
   List<String> cars;

   @XmlElement(name="car")
   public List<String> getCars() {
       return cars;
   }

   public void setCars(List<String> cars) {
       this.cars = cars;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cars` property should be of type `List<Car>` and not `List<String>`.  Then your `Car` type should have two properties:  `name` and `color`.

**For More Information**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics